# how do i make a service run a script outside of session 0

Tags: powershell, batch-file, cmd, psexec, windows-server-2012-r2

The UPS software I am using has functionality to run a script on the management PC (PC1) when it goes into battery mode. I have come up with a powershell script (ShutdownVM.ps1) that works fine on its own to Invoke-Commands on the VM server; shutting down VM's gracefully and turning off the host machine (SERVER). The first problem arose when the UPS software could not directly run a .ps1 file.

Simple enough, I thought I would make a simple .bat (shutdown.bat) file to run the .ps1 file on PC1 to shut everything off on SERVER. Running my .bat file from the desktop pc worked perfectly, but as the UPS software would run it as a service, my poor .bat file would run from Session 0.

Here is the code i used in Shutdown.bat:

```
@echo on
Powershell.exe -executionpolicy unrestricted -command C:\Windows\ShutdownVM.ps1
```

The interactive services manager would pop up and my computer would hang and finally the UPS software would turn it off and I'd be back to square one, with SERVER and its VM's still running. So I thought I would download and use PSExec to execute my shutdown.bat file.

I made another .bat file and called it PSExec.bat and below is the code in it:

```
@echo on
psexec.exe -accepteula \\PC1 -h -u user -p pass -i 2 C:\Windows\shutdown.bat
```

Finally! It tries to run! Upon checking the interactive services manager, it showed the PSExec was throwing the error "the system cannot find the file specified"

["The System Cannot Find The File Specified"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rXzQZ.png)

I have no idea what file it is even looking for, I have double, triple checked the path names in my scripts and still have no idea as to what it is doing. If anyone could shed any light (or let me know of an easier way to achieve what I am trying to do) that would be great. Thanks!

-F

Comment: Does PC1 have `C:\Windows\shutdown.bat` or are you after `c:\Windows\system32\shutdown.exe` with a few switches?

Comment: shutdown.bat, psexec.bat and shutdownvm.ps1 all exist inside PS1's C:\Windows (i put them there)

Comment: does it have access to run something in the `c:\windows` folder? maybe try moving them to `c:\temp` and see if that works

Comment: Nope :( Still got the same message "Error Establishing connection with psexec service on PC1"
"The system cannot find the file specified"

Comment: Does the psexec bat work interactively?

Comment: @AndrewSavinykh yes it does. As long as i run the psexec batch file myself as an administrator the whole process works perfectly.